# JavaScript code for changing bg color in existing header menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my header to change the background color when being redirected to another page of my website. Right now the background color is only applied to  my "Home" page (HTML code below). The menu should look like this:

[image: Home]

[image: Angebote]

I'm not experienced in JavaScript, but I have looked into it a bit. I tried using if, else, if else, redirecting the page with jQuery and changing the color with examples like this one from W3Schools:

```
<p id="p2">example</p>
<script>
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "grey";
</script>
```

Unfortunately none of these worked and I don't know what objects/functions I need to use.

This is the part of my header menu I have already shown above in HTML:

```
<ul class="navigationboxL">
    <li><a class="aktuell" title="Home" href="http://ten.nis">| Home</a></li>
    <li><a title="Angebote" href="http://ten.nis/?page_id=29">| Angebote</a></li>
    <li><a title="Sponsoring" href="http://ten.nis/?page_id=31">| Sponsoring</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS: https://www.promotennis.ch/StyleSheet.css.

Any kind of help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: How does it handle the redirect to the different pages? Is it loaded in via ajax or does it go to the site specified in the href tag?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question.
If I go to: "https://www.promotennis.ch/index.html" I see the menu and on the subpage the background of the active item is also set.

Comment: It goes to the site specified in the href tag.

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question but I'm recreating that website and the problem I have is on my testing site.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any JS for this you should do this with CSS only. I think the styling of the active Element is done with the `aktuell` Class.

So to set another element as the active element all you have to do is remove `class="aktuell"` from the element and add it to the active element:

```
<ul class="navigationboxL">
  <li><a title="Home" href="http://ten.nis">| Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="aktuell" title="Angebote" href="http://ten.nis/?page_id=29">| Angebote</a></li>
  <li><a title="Sponsoring" href="http://ten.nis/?page_id=31">| Sponsoring</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another little tip: You can do the | with css only, the way you did it now it is just added text. You can achieve this with `border-left: 1px solid black` (or whatever color you need.) Then remove the border-left for the first element.

Comment: There's only one header file for all pages. I already tried doing that, but when putting the class to any other href tag only that href tag has the color I set in my CSS, just like in the code you wrote. But I want the color to change every time the user is being redirected to another page. So for example: Home = bg darker, other elements = white and so on. Also, I only have to recreate the website and since it was that way before I'll have to leave it like that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to change the class dynamically. If your site is coded in PHP then PHP will have to handle setting the class correctly. Sadly, explaining this would be too much for this question but you can google for php add class dynamically or something.